# Error inflating android.support.v17.leanback.widget.TitleView

Tags: android, television, android-tv

I'm testing the new support library leanback to design apps for TV, and i have a error ever android try to inflate the BrowseFragment and it throws this exception and don't know how to solve it. Thank you so much for your help.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class      android.support.v17.leanback.widget.TitleView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:816)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment.onCreateView(BrowseFragment.java:674)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:866)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
        at com.engel.engeldroid.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:28)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1700)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:890)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:684)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1447)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:443)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:603)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/browse_fragment"
    android:name="android.support.v17.leanback.app.BrowseFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: Is there a second stanza to your stack trace, after what you have pasted here, such as a "Caused by" second stack trace? Usually, there is something more to the "Error inflating class" crash. Also, are you using `Theme.Leanback` for this activity? [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Presentation/Decktastic), among other things, has a leanback activity that uses a `BrowseFragment`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, i missed to put the Leanback theme as default. :P

Answer (score 1):

As was mention in the comment the issue is related to the theme of the `Activity` in which leanback is used.
Check if your activity uses `Theme.Leanback` theme directly in `AndroidManifest`

```
    <activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback" />
```

or your AppTheme derived from `Theme.Leanback`

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Leanback" >
    // your custom attributes
 </style>
```